# How can I upload a file to server with node and socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, fs

Ok so I've got a `html <input type='file' />`, and I'm trying to send the selected file to the server, so I can then save.

But at the moment all I can do is get a `<Buffer`  and then convert that `<Buffer` to a `base64` value. I don't want to store the `base64`, I actually want to store the `file` itself on the server so I can then reference it as an `<image src='folder/fileThatWasUploaded.png' />` .

At the moment I'm using `socket.io` to send messages to other users in a chat and `node` on the backend to save messages to the DB and etc.

Here is the client side code that I'm using to get the file and emit it to the server.

```
$("#imgUpload").on('change',function(){
     var selectedFile = this.files[0];
     console.log(selectedFile);
    
     // Send message to chat and save to mongo: 
     socket.emit('clientMessage', {
         message: $('#chatMessage').val(), 
         name: user.name,
         userId: user.userId,
         image: selectedFile
     });
          // selectedFile.convertToBase64(function(base64){
          //      base64Img = base64;
          // }) 
});
```

Here is the server side code that I'm using to recieve emitted data from the socket, It's is then suppose to recieve the file and save it to a folder. But instead of getting a file I get a `<Buffer` , I cannot write a `<Buffer 89 50 4e 4 .....` to a folder.

```
// When user sends message, emit it back to others
    socket.on('clientMessage', function(data) {
        console.log(chatId);

        // Send the message to database and emit back to other users
        createMessage(data, chatId, function() {
          console.log(data.image); // This prints out a buffer
             // This is suppose to write the file, BUT IT CAN'T WRITE A BUFFER
             // fs.writeFile("/public/images/", data.image, function(err) {
            //     if(err) {
            //         return console.log(err);
            //     }

            //     console.log("The file was saved!");
            // });
```

Does anyone have any ideas to what I can do?

#### Edit:

I've used the following bit of code to convert the `buffer` to a base64 value , once it has been converted to a base64 string it will be saved as a `.jpg`. Is this a good and efficient way of doing this?

```
  fs.writeFile("imageConversion.jpg", new Buffer(data.image, "base64"), function(err) {
       if(err){
            console.log("Error: ", err);
            return;
       }
       console.log("image converted and saved to dir");
  });
```

Comment: `socket.io`. Sorry, just proofreading goes a long way.